# multibrowser chatting with flas-socketio

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, gevent-socketio

I am trying to create a simple multi browser chat web application. I thought I finished creating it. But when I try run it I get 500 status and

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

Not really sure why this is occurring. I am doing this project in Flask and I am currently learning at the same time. Because I am currently learning Flask and Flask-socketio and websockets.

chatty.py:

```
from gevent import monkey
# Do all of the default monkey patching (calls every other function in this module.
monkey.patch_all()

from threading import Thread
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO, emit
from time import strftime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'
socketio = SocketIO(app)
thread = None


@app.route('/')
def index():
    global thread
    if thread is None:
        #thread = Thread(target=background_thread)
        thread.start()
    return render_template('index.html')

# handle messages
@socketio.on('send message')
def handle_message(message):
    #msg = strftime("%H:%M:%S") + ': ' + str(message)
    emit('response', 
            {'data': strftime("%H:%M:%S") + ': ' + message['data']}, 
            broadcast = True)

@socketio.on('connect')
def conn():
    emit('response', {'data': 'Connected'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

index.html:

```
    <html>
    <!-- jQuery and socket.io -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var socket = io.connect('https://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

            socket.on('connect', function() {
                socket.emit('', {data: 'I\'m connected!'});
            });

            socket.on('response', function(msg) {
                $('#log').append(msg.data);
            });

            $('form#broadcast').submit(function() {
                socket.emit('send message', { data: $('#msg').val()});
            })

        })
    </script>

    <form id="broadcast" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="message" id="msg" placeholder="Enter message here...">
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>

    <h2>Chat</h2>
    <div id="log"></div>

</html>
```

Comment: In sum, you should be able to see the log message by adding `import logging; loggin.basicConfig()` to the top of your Python file (it looks like socketio doesn't properly configure a `NullHandler` for its logging).  If the linked question doesn't answer your question, please edit and clarify what you still need help with and I'll re-open.

Comment: @SeanVieira I believe i fixed the issue but I can't seem to build the application I am trying to make. Basically I want to build the chat app following this http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent/page/0#comments (Only the broadcast feature)

Comment: I'd recommend that you try and reduce the problem to the minimum viable application that re-creates your new issue and post another question :-)